# Android Application gets a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been having an issue with starting my application recently. It was working fine a few weeks back but during that time I made a few changes including importing refractoring it(I added a bunch of packages but then reverted those changes), updating from the ADT from the android site (which still runs on Eclipse Juno) to eclipse Kepler (and I downloaded the ADT plugin) and I also imported it to my new laptop (also using Kepler). Now when I import the application using `Import -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace` I get an error message saying that "Could not set the project desciption from "(myappname)" because the project description file (.project) is out of sync with the file system.". If I ignore this message and continue, and run the application on my phone LogCat gives me an error message ClassNotFoundException on my main launcher activity.

I've looked around and tried to solve this problem by rebuilding the path (with android private libraries checked). That's the only relevant fix I've found but it doesn't work.

I should point out a few things that might or might not help:
-I tried to run an older version of the application and that works (after import and on Kepler even though it was written on the Juno Eclipse).
-My application imports the support package v7-compat (which worked before all the changes)

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days now and with no luck. Any and all help would be appreciated. Oh and if anyone needs more information to help me solve this just ask.

**Edit:**
Here is the error log:

```
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.Spit.pocketbook/com.Spit.pocketbook.SwipeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Spit.pocketbook.SwipeActivity
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Spit.pocketbook.SwipeActivity
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
01-27 19:22:59.603: E/AndroidRuntime(16471):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks ahead of time, 
Spit

Comment: `NoClassFoundException` does not exist. post your stacktrace.

Comment: Have you tried after importing your project into Eclipse, right click it and click "Refresh"?

Comment: @njzk2 Sorry I has the exception in the title wrong but now it's fixed and I posted the error log too.

Comment: I have refreshed but the issue persists sadly.

Answer (score 0):

A class that was declared in manifest was not found in code.

Check that package and class names are the same in your manifest and code. Based on the stacktrace generated by data in your manifest, your code should have `class SwipeActivity` in `package com.Spit.pocketbook`. Note that class and package names are case sensitive. By convention, package names are all lowercase so the capital `S` in the package name looks suspicious.

Comment: That's not it. I've checked that all the class names and package name in the manifest match the ones in my source. I have a feeling this is more of those annoying eclipse behind the scenes mix ups rather than me having done something obviously wrong (but of course I could be wrong about that). And the capital "S" thing, yeah I need to get around to fixing that. It's on the list.